# Ajax page fully loaded then update the DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I want to update the DIV content until AJAX page is fully loaded, Every jQuery and css in the ajax page.

[image]

Comment: what does `I want to update the DIV content until AJAX page is fully loaded` mean?

Comment: Do you mean like a `loading` state?

Comment: Have you tried the `jQuery(document).ready()` event?

Comment: Actually , In Ajax page i am creating a  box listing like Pinterest , But ajax page is calling it too  fast before page is rendered fully and design is broken.

Comment: Do you have an example using http://jsfiddle.net/ or the like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are inside success is becouase on data you have all html data (or json or the data retrieved by the server). Then, you add this data to the div content and then browser will be creating the layout (dom + css = CSSDOM => paint => layout => composite for example). Try to execute a function after DOM on div #descDiv are ready to use like:

```
$("#descDiv").ready( function() {
   // div has data ready to use
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Your solution works for me, Now when i am using the ready function i am getting proper data and all the JavaScript and jquery function is also working.